# I get different results than expected

Tags: c, variables

I usually encounter the same problem while making small codes , so i decided to ask you guys

When i run this program i get some big numbers for exemple : a=1565434  ,b=5385975

i think its the default values which equivalent in the system , please tell me how to attach the both procedure , affichage(means display) and saisie(means seisuze) so there will be a connexion between variables , so i can seize the values and display them , thank you !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void saisie()
{
    int m,i,X[m];
    printf("Combien de case dans le tableau : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
        printf("Donne la note pour la case %d : ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&X[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void affichage()
{
    int m,i,X[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf(" Case %d : %d",i,X[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    saisie();
    affichage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causes undefined behaviour:

```
int m,i,X[m];
```

because you use `m` before you have given it a value.  Instead, you must set the value for `m` before writing `int X[m];` .

Also, the `afficiage` function outputs uninitialized variables.  The variables `m` `i` `X` in `afficiage` are different from the variables in `saisie`. To fix this you will need to learn about passing variables between functions (particularly `m` and `X`); whichever book you are using should cover that as it is very basic to C programming.